# Lógica de query SQL o MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día,

Chicos, en el sistema que trabajo existe un módulo que se llama RESERVAS o BOOKING, es un sistema hotelero, cuando abro una opción del sistema para mover la reserva a otra habitación me deberían aparecer las habitaciones que están disponibles por esas fechas.

En la tabla de la base de datos hay dos campos llamados date_input y date_output ahora viene mi duda: necesito decir que: no me traíga las habitaciones que estén entre el date_input y el date_output, así estoy realizando mi query:

```
SELECT 
  room_number 
FROM
  rooms_demo a 
WHERE a.`room_number` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
  WHERE b.`date_input` >= '2017-08-01' 
    AND b.`date_output` <= '2017-08-08')
```

En un query simplemente dice b.date_input >= '2017-08-01' AND b.date_input <= '2017-08-08'.

Agradezco comentarios y ayudas.

Comment: ¿Deseas filtrar las habitaciones que no están disponibles? si es así, ¿estas queriendo comparar con la fecha actual?

Comment: Para excluir registros puedes probar usando el **NOT IN**

Comment: ¿Qué significan los dos asteriscos al principio y al final?

Comment: Nada en especifico 

¿Deseas filtrar las habitaciones que no están disponibles? si es así, ¿estas queriendo comparar con la fecha actual? Lo estoy haciendo según las fechas que envió como parámetro.

Comment: A ver ¿`date_input` y `date_output` son campos de la tabla `booking`? ¿Si escribes los WHERE sin poner comillas simples a los nombres de columna, así: **`WHERE a.room_number`**   y  **`WHERE b.date_input >= '2017-08-01' 
    AND b.date_output <= '2017-08-08'`** no funciona?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando la tablas y sus relaciones? Si se puede las sentencias para la creación (`CREATE`) de las tablas afectadas y un conjunto de datos en cada tabla  (`INSERT`). Además cuál es resultado que obtuviste de la consulta y cuál es el resultado que deseas obtener.

Comment: ¿Estás teniendo en cuenta que si no pones hora se considera 00:00 por defecto por lo que 2017-08-08 no estará incluido en las fechas del select?

Comment: si, la hora la guardo en otro campo, después de arreglar este query se concatena la hora con CONCAT y queda bien, gracias

Comment: @AndresGaleano La mejor forma de trabajar con fechas es usando un campo de tipo `timestamp` en donde se almacenan la fecha y la hora. Después en la consulta `SELECT` se puede manipular el campo y obtener la parte que necesitas.

Comment: @AndresGaleano serias tan amable de poner todo lo que fuiste comentando en las respuestas en la pregunta? no se entiende a donde queres llegar, ni todos los casos que queres cubrir, porque sin darte cuenta estas soltando datos a cuentagotas. Por ejemplos claros de los datos que quieres cubrir.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de llegar a lo que quieres pero basandonos en la consulta que nos muestras solo tendrias que agregar **NOT** IN

```
SELECT 
  room_number 
FROM
  rooms_demo a 
WHERE a.`room_number` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
  WHERE b.`date_input` >= '2017-08-01' 
    AND b.`date_output` <= '2017-08-08')
```

Saludos

Comment: Si, claro, pero esa no es mi duda especificamente, pegue mal el script, ya lo corrijo.

Comment: Ya no entendi muy bien lo que nos preguntas, tu script debe filtrar las habitaciones que no esten en las fechas dadas con el NOT IN, lo quieres reducir a un solo query sin subconsulta o como?

Comment: no, es que con ese query no esta trayendo los datos correctos dado que son dos campos independientes date_input, date_output.

Me explico: si fuera un query común y corriente simplemente haría un query donde b.date_input >= '2017-08-01' AND b.date_input <= '2017-08-08'; la diferencia es que no es con un campo, sino de los dos que funcionan de igual forma, estan enlazados pero son independientes los cuales son: fecha de entrada y fecha salida.

Comment: @AndresGaleano realmente no te estás explicando correctamente. Qué significa `estan enlazados pero son independientes`?. Por qué esta consulta no está trayendo los datos correctos?, pareciera ser lo que explicaste en tu pregunta que quieres obtiener. Sería mejor que postees datos de ejemplo de las tablas y el resultado que quieres obtener

Comment: Es que es algo complejo de explicar, ejemplo:

Si la habitación 106 tiene una reserva el 2017-08-01 y saldría el 2017-08-08 y tengo otra habitación la número 202 entra el 2017-08-01 PERO sale el 2017-08-10 el script que pegue en el post solo deja de mostrar la hab 202, yo necesito que no se muestren ni la 202 ni la 106

Comment: Me sigue siendo confuso sin ver la estructura de la tabla y un set de resultados esperados

Answer (score 1):

Ok, creo que ya entiendo el problema. La verdad es que la solución más sencilla para tí sería que crearas una tabla "Calendario" en la que tengas simplemente todos los días (una fila por día) e hicieras un `JOIN` con esa tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT rd.`room_number`
FROM rooms_demo rd
WHERE rd.`room_number` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.`room_number`
    FROM Calendario c
    INNER JOIN booking b
        ON c.fecha BETWEEN b.`date_input` AND b.`date_output`
    WHERE c.fecha BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-08')
```

Una forma sin la tabla "Calendario" sería:

```
SELECT rd.`room_number`
FROM rooms_demo rd
WHERE rd.`room_number` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.`room_number`
    FROM booking b
    WHERE b.`date_input` BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-08'
    AND b.`date_output` >= '2017-08-01')
```

Para tu nuevo inconveniente podrías usar:

```
SELECT rd.`room_number`
FROM rooms_demo rd
WHERE rd.`room_number` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.`room_number`
    FROM booking b
    WHERE (b.`date_input` BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-08'
    AND b.`date_output` >= '2017-08-01')
    OR (b.`date_output` >= '2017-08-01' AND b.`date_input`<= '2017-08-08')
    )
```

Ahora, en serio, todo esto lo podrías evitar con una simple tabla Calendario

Comment: Gracias Lamak por la respuesta respuesta, pero no puedo crear una nueva tabla

Comment: @AndresGaleano actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: así como la has puesto me ha funcionado, pero resulto un nuevo inconveniente, ya que solo me traía las habitaciones donde la fecha de entrada fueran desde el 02017-08-01, Pero si la habitación entra el 2017-07-31 y sale el 2017-08-08 ? no me la muestra, solo muestra la que fue registrada hoy, hice un query el cual funciona hasta el momento. lo pego en la siguiente respuesta al comentario.

Comment: SELECT 
  room_number 
FROM
  rooms_demo a 
WHERE a.`room_number` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
  WHERE (
      b.`date_output` >= '2017-08-01'
    ) 
    AND (
      b.`date_input` <= '2017-08-08' 
    ) 
    AND b.`status_booking` != 'delete')

Comment: @AndresGaleano La verdad, este tipo de situaciones es donde una tabla calendario es la solución más usada, en vez de todo este manejo extraño de fechas. Trataría de ver la posibilidad de crearla, es una simple tabla que va a tener poquísimas filas

Comment: @AndresGaleano ok, volví a actualizar mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Esto, entiendo que resolvería el problema

```
SELECT 
  room_number 
FROM
  rooms_demo a 
WHERE a.`room_number` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
    WHERE ([fecha desde] between b.date_input and b.date_output or [fecha hasta] between b.date_input and b.date_output)
          or
          (b.date_input   between [fecha desde] and [fecha desde] or b.date_output between [fecha desde] and [fecha desde])
 )
```

Reemplaza obviamente `[fecha desde]` y `[fecha desde]` por los valores que elijas. Básicamente lo que intento en esta consulta es que puedan darse estas condiciones:

- Qué `[fecha desde]` este dentro de los rangos de `date_input` y `date_output` O
- Qué `[fecha desde]` este dentro de los rangos de `date_input` y `date_output` O
- Qué `date_input` este dentro de los rangos de `[fecha desde]` y `[fecha desde]` O
- Qué `date_output` este dentro de los rangos de `[fecha desde]` y `[fecha desde]`

### Actualización

Creo que nos complicamos la vida con las consultas y encaramos mal el problema. Si pensamos en que por un lado tenemos habitaciones que tienen un intervalo de tiempo y por otro lado una selección de fechas que también es un intervalo de tiempo, para saber cuales son las que estarán ocupadas podemos hacerlo fácil "negando" la condición de [conjuntos disjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjuntos_disjuntos) de ambos intervalos. Y un conjunto de intervalos disjunto se puede calcular de manera sencilla, por lo que entiendo podríamos estar haciendo:

```
(SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
    WHERE NOT ([fecha desde] > b.date_output or [fecha hasta] < b.date_output)
 )
```

Y con esto tendriamos las habitación `NOT IN`

Comment: Si, se asimila a lo que estoy haciendo, lo complejo es el OR, éste me multiplica los datos, hice algo así y esta funcionando hasta el momento

SELECT 
  room_number 
FROM
  rooms_demo a 
WHERE a.`room_number` IN 
  (SELECT 
    b.`room_number` 
  FROM
    booking b 
  WHERE (
      b.`date_output` >= '2017-08-01'
    ) 
    AND (
      b.`date_input` <= '2017-08-08' 
      AND b.`date_output` <= '2017-08-08'
    ))

Comment: Andrés creo que no te funcionaría con una habitación en este rango `2017-07-07 - 2017-07-09`, intenta con la consulta que te pasé.

Comment: Andrés, actualice mi respuesta, ahora sí contempla todos los casos.