# ¿Consulta sql con 4 fechas y verifcar que no se crucen las fechas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con estos campos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Queremos traer los id's de autos que que estén disponibles en un rango de fechas que recibo de dos inputs que serian cuando quieren sacar el carro y cuando lo quieren regresar. Esta fechas las comparo con las columnas fechaHoraSalida y fechaHoraRegreso.

```
select idAuto from contratos 
where (CAST(fechaHoraRegreso AS DATE) < '2017-09-11')
and ((CAST(fechaHoraSalida AS DATE) > '2017-09-12') or (CAST(fechaHoraSalida 
AS DATE) < '2017-09-12'))
)
```

El problema es que hay fechas que no están en el rango y no las muestra

Comment: No se si esta duplicada, pero tu pregunta es muy parecida a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92053/l%C3%B3gica-de-query-sql-o-mysql/92067#92067) y de manera más general te recomiendo leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos). Saludos.

Comment: Si ya lo habia checado antes y no me resulto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes resolver así:

```
SELECT idAuto 
       FROM contratos 
       WHERE CAST(fechaHoraSalida AS DATE) < '2017-09-11'
             OR CAST(fechaHoraRegreso AS DATE) > '2017-09-12'
```

Obviamente asumo que `fechaHoraSalida` y `fechaHoraRegreso` y el periodo solicitado (FechaDesde/FechaHasta) son consistentes. Lo que hacemos es recuperar todos los `contratos` cuya Fecha de Salida sea menor a nuestra FechaDesde O cuya Fecha de Regreso sea mayor a nuestra FechaHasta.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos encontre una posible solucion que es esta:

```
select idAuto from contratos 
where 
(CAST(fechaHoraSalida AS DATE)  between '2017-09-22' and  '2017-09-25' )
or
( CAST(fechaHoraRegreso AS DATE)  between '2017-09-22' and '2017-09-25')
or
((CAST(fechaHoraSalida AS DATE)<'2017-09-22')
and
(CAST(fechaHoraRegreso AS DATE)> '2017-09-22'))
or
((CAST(fechaHoraRegreso AS DATE)>'2017-09-25')
and
(CAST(fechaHoraSalida AS DATE)< '2017-09-25'))
```

Si alguien tiene alguna otra sugerencia es bien recibida